# No translation for devise flashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have `ru.yml` and `en.yml` files, the section I need looks like this:

```
en:
  devise:
    failure:
      already_authenticated: You are already signed in.
```

```
ru:
  devise:
    failure:
      already_authenticated: Вы уже вошли в систему.
```

The thing is, that no matter what language the user chooses, this (and several others) alert messages will be in russian.

My controllers have `around_action :localize_request`, which should determine the locale. And it works just fine for any other funcionality on the site, except for this particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in the Devise gem -- https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5247

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be a possible bug from devise. Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5080) they discussed something similar and created a PR to fix it that I think is the reason why you can't translate your message.

As a workaround, maybe you can try to make this change to test if it works:

```yaml
ru:
  devise:
    failure:
      user: # <<<
        already_authenticated: Вы уже вошли в систему.
```